# Why does logging not work when running a Flask app with werkzeug?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, werkzeug

So here is a copy paste example that reproduces the problem.

```
import logging

from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

def app_builder(app_name, log_file):

    app = Flask(app_name)
    app.debug = True

    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)

    return app

def _simple(env, resp):
    resp(b'200 OK', [(b'Content-Type', b'text/plain')])
    return [b'root']

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = app_builder(app_name='app', log_file='app.log')

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return '<a href="/app/error">click for error</a>'

    @app.route('/error')
    def error():
        1/0
        return 'error page'

    app2 = app_builder(app_name='app2', log_file='app2.log')

    @app2.route('/')
    def index():
        return 'you are getting responses from app2'

    app.debug = True
    app2.debug = True

    application = DispatcherMiddleware(_simple, {
        '/app':     app,
        '/app2':    app2
        })

    run_simple(hostname='localhost',
               port=5000,
               application=application,
               use_reloader=True,
               use_debugger=True)
```

To make an error show up navigate to `http://localhost:5000/app/error`, I want to know why the stack trace doesn't show up in the `app.log` file. I assume that the `DispatcherMiddleware` or `run_simple` are somehow catching the exception before it can be logged. If I run only the `app` instance using `app.run()` the error logging works fine.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger such as [PuDB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb)? Drop a breakpoint at the error route and follow the calls, see where the error goes.

Comment: You need to tell the log to write it down. `app.logger.debug("My error")`

Comment: @iScrE4m but why do I need to do that, what about werkzeug is causing exceptions to not be logged (in contrast to the way it works when I use `app.run()`)?

Comment: Is it possible that `app.logger` has a logging different from `DEBUG`?  Try to do: `app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`.  Keep in mind that a logger ignores all messages with a level lower than the one set. *After this* all remaining messagges are sent to the handlers, and the handlers will filter them by level again. **However** adding a handler with level `DEBUG` on a logger that has a higher level will result in the handler never receiving messagges.

Comment: @Bakuriu iirc the default level for `app.logger` is `logging.NOTSET` so that shouldn't be the issue. I tested your suggestion anyways and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal exception handler is not called when `app.debug = True`. Looking
in the code of `app.py` in Flask:

```
def log_exception(self, exc_info):
    """Logs an exception.  This is called by :meth:`handle_exception`
    if debugging is disabled and right before the handler is called.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    The default implementation logs the exception as error on the
    :attr:`logger`.
```

Indeed, when setting `app.debug = True` the exceptions propagation is set
to True explicitly, which prevents `log_exception` to be called. Here is an excerpt of the documentation (emphasis is mine):

> PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS:     explicitly enable or disable the propagation of exceptions. If not set or explicitly set to None this is **implicitly true** if either TESTING or **DEBUG is true**.

So, I managed to get both werkzeug debugging and logging working happily
together with a little tweak and the following code:

```
import logging

from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
## NEW CODE HERE
import functools
from flask._compat import reraise

def my_log_exception(exc_info, original_log_exception=None):
    original_log_exception(exc_info)
    exc_type, exc, tb = exc_info
    # re-raise for werkzeug
    reraise(exc_type, exc, tb)
## 

def app_builder(app_name, log_file):
    app = Flask(app_name)
    app.debug = True
    app.config.update(PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS=False)

    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)

    ## NEW CODE
    app.log_exception = functools.partial(my_log_exception,  original_log_exception=app.log_exception)
    ##

    return app

# rest of your code is unchanged
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ibeex/3257877) which talks about logging in flask. The comment by andyxning (commented on Apr 18, 2015) mentions this - `if app.debug is True then all log level above DEBUG will be logged to stderr(StreamHandler)`.

The comment also has a link to the source code of [flask/logging.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/logging.py). The `create_logger` method creates an instance of `DebugHandler` which inherits from `StreamHandler` class.

If you print `app.logger.handlers` you can see that it has an object of `flask.logging.DebugHandler`.

```
print app.logger.handlers
[<flask.logging.DebugHandler object at 0x110315090>]
```

This DebugHandler is probably used when `app.debug is set to true` and hence the stack trace gets printed on the console.

Hope this is what you are looking for.